# Swap the linklist nodes in c elegantly

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I want swap the nodes in Linklist.

I write the function `swap`, but It doesn't work when the node next to the node.

For example, I want to swap the node4 and node5. It is wrong.

```
void swap (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head)
{
  LINK* pre_node1 = search(pos1-1, head);
  LINK* pre_node2 = search(pos2-1, head);

  LINK* current_node1 = pre_node1 -> next;
  LINK* current_node2 = pre_node2 -> next;

  LINK* next_node1 = search(pos1+1, head);
  LINK* next_node2 = search(pos2+1, head);

  pre_node1 -> next = current_node2;
  pre_node2 -> next = current_node1;

  current_node1 -> next = next_node2;
  current_node2 -> next = next_node1;
}
```

I test the function:

```
    for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
      insert(i,head,i);
    printf ("original array: \n");
    print(head);

    printf ("swap node2 and node7: \n");
    swap(2,7,head);
    print(head);

    printf ("swap node1 and node9: \n");
    swap(1,9,head);
    print(head);

/*
    It does not work!
    swap(4,5,head);
    print(head);
*/
```

I can swap the contents by using `swap2`. but I think it is ugly.

```
void swap2 (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head)
{
  LINK* node1 = search(pos1, head);
  LINK* node2 = search(pos2, head);
  int tem = node1->data;
  node1->data = node2->data;
  node2->data = tem;
}
```

I want swap the nodes. Please tell me how to correct the `swap`.

Here are my the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linklist {
  int data;
  struct linklist * next;
}LINK;

LINK* createnode (int element,LINK *first);
LINK* search (int j,LINK *head);
void insert (int ele, LINK *head, int pos);
void delete (LINK *head, int pos);
void print (LINK *head);
void swap (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head);
void swap2 (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head);
void swap3(int i,int j,LINK *head);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    LINK *head;
    head = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
    head-> next = NULL;

    for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
      insert(i,head,i);
    printf ("original array: \n");
    print(head);

    printf ("swap node2 and node7: \n");
    swap(2,7,head);
    print(head);

    printf ("swap node1 and node9: \n");
    swap(1,9,head);
    print(head);
/*
    It does not work!
    swap(4,5,head);
    print(head);
*/

/*
  The function swap2 only swap the data, I want swap the nodes.
    printf ("swap node4 and node5: \n");
    swap2(4,5,head);
    print(head);
*/
    printf ("swap node4 and node5: \n");
    swap3(4,5,head);
    print(head);

}

LINK* createnode(int element,LINK *first)
{
    LINK *ele;
    ele = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
    ele -> data = element;
    ele -> next = first -> next;
    first -> next = ele;
    return first;
}

LINK* search (int j,LINK * head)
{
    LINK *tem;
    tem = head;
    int i = 0;
    while (tem -> next !=NULL && i < j)
    {
        tem = tem->next;
        i++;
    }
    if (tem != NULL && i==j)
        return tem;
    else return NULL;
}

void insert (int ele, LINK *head, int pos)
{
    LINK *prenode = search(pos-1,head);
    LINK *d = createnode(ele, prenode);
    if (prenode == NULL)
      printf ("insert error! \n");
}

void delete (LINK *head, int pos)
{
    LINK *prenode = search (pos-1,head);
    if (prenode != NULL)
    {
        LINK *nownode = prenode -> next;
        prenode -> next = nownode -> next;
        free(nownode);
    }
    else  printf("delete error!\n");
}

void print (LINK* head)
 {
     int j=0;
     LINK *p;
     p = head->next;
     while (p != NULL)
     {
         printf("%d ", p->data);
         p = p -> next;
         j++;
     }
     printf ("\n");
}

void swap (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head)
{
  LINK* pre_node1 = search(pos1-1, head);
  LINK* pre_node2 = search(pos2-1, head);

  LINK* current_node1 = pre_node1 -> next;
  LINK* current_node2 = pre_node2 -> next;

  LINK* next_node1 = search(pos1+1, head);
  LINK* next_node2 = search(pos2+1, head);

  pre_node1 -> next = current_node2;
  pre_node2 -> next = current_node1;

  current_node1 -> next = next_node2;
  current_node2 -> next = next_node1;
}

void swap2 (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head)
{
  LINK* node1 = search(pos1, head);
  LINK* node2 = search(pos2, head);
  int tem = node1->data;
  node1->data = node2->data;
  node2->data = tem;
}

void swap3(int i,int j,LINK *head)
{
    LINK* previous_i = search(i-1,head);
    LINK* previous_j =  search(j-1,head);
    LINK* adress_i = search(i,head);
    LINK* adress_j = search(j,head);
    LINK* latter_i = search(i+1,head);
    LINK* latter_j = search(j+1,head);

    if (adress_i->next != adress_j && adress_j->next != adress_i)
    {
    previous_i -> next = adress_j;
    adress_j -> next = latter_i;
    previous_j -> next = adress_i;
    adress_i -> next = latter_j;
    }
    else if (adress_i->next == adress_j)
    {
        previous_i -> next = adress_j;
        adress_j -> next = adress_i;
        adress_i ->next = latter_j;
    }
    else if (adress_j->next == adress_i)
    {
        previous_j -> next = adress_i;
        adress_i -> next = adress_j;
        adress_j ->next = latter_i;
    }
}
```

Finally, I write the `swap3`. But I think it is so complex. It is the right.

```
void swap3(int i,int j,LINK *head)
{
    LINK* previous_i = search(i-1,head);
    LINK* previous_j =  search(j-1,head);
    LINK* adress_i = search(i,head);
    LINK* adress_j = search(j,head);
    LINK* latter_i = search(i+1,head);
    LINK* latter_j = search(j+1,head);

    if (adress_i->next != adress_j && adress_j->next != adress_i)
    {
    previous_i -> next = adress_j;
    adress_j -> next = latter_i;
    previous_j -> next = adress_i;
    adress_i -> next = latter_j;
    }
    else if (adress_i->next == adress_j)
    {
        previous_i -> next = adress_j;
        adress_j -> next = adress_i;
        adress_i ->next = latter_j;
    }
    else if (adress_j->next == adress_i)
    {
        previous_j -> next = adress_i;
        adress_i -> next = adress_j;
        adress_j ->next = latter_i;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To *remove* a node you need to change *two* pointers (same for insert) To swap two nodes you need two deletes+two inserts. Which ones? Paper+pencil: draw.

Comment: Thanks.  I solve the problems. I add the codes into the question. But I think it is so complex.

Comment: Use a debugger to see step by step where your not working implementation behaves different from what you expected.

Comment: Thanks. I solve the problem by using pencil and paper. My codes are right. My idea is wrong. Thinks your advice. @MrSmith42

Comment: The `.` (dot) and `->` (arrow) operators bind very tightly and should not be written with spaces on either side of them — `structure.member` and `pointer->member` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are cleaner ways to solve this, but this is my tw cents:
tested with:

```
swap(2,7,head);
swap(1,9,head);
swap(4,5,head);
swap(6,5,head);
```

---

```
void swap (int pos1, int pos2, LINK *head)
{
    LINK* pre_node1 = search(pos1-1, head);
    LINK* pre_node2 = search(pos2-1, head);

    LINK* current_node1 = pre_node1 -> next;
    LINK* current_node2 = pre_node2 -> next;

    LINK* next_node1 = search(pos1+1, head);
    LINK* next_node2 = search(pos2+1, head);

        pre_node1 -> next = current_node2;
        pre_node2->next = current_node1;

    if (current_node1 != next_node2)
        current_node1 -> next = next_node2;
    else
        current_node1 -> next = current_node2;
    if (current_node2 != next_node1)
        current_node2->next = next_node1;
    else
        current_node2->next = current_node1;
}
```

Comment: @Dagan I do not see where the head is changed provided that one swapped node is the head.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If I understand the original code correctly `head` is static and always used as the first element - this solution refers to this restriction - if I am wrong or one does not wish to implement in this manner then you are correct - thanks